# Password field outputs in plain text using console.log()

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I discovered something interesting today while messing around with the password fields in Google Chrome.

Interestingly, outputting the value of an input of type `'password'` to console using `console.log(password);` totally negates the idea of obscuring the password fields by printing the password in plain text in the console.

```js
var password = $('#password').val();
console.log(password);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control text-box single-line input-validation-valid" id="password" name="password" type="password" value="test">
```

Would this cause any security issues at all?

Comment: Reading the source code would tell you that with no JavaScript.... That is why you DO NOT set password values.

Comment: if you don't have any people around you watching your dev console, this shouldn't be a security issue.

Comment: In my opinion that isn't a problem. Password fields hide passwords for real people behind your back. The browser needs the value to submit it and that's why you can log the value.

Comment: A security issue is that it is trivial for an extension to read a password on any page that it has access to. So be really careful with what extensions you install in your browser.

Comment: @epascarello The value is set for the example as it saves me having to write an event handler to output the value to console. No-one would do that in practice...

Comment: @MasterYoda um, you would be surprised.... And of course you need to read the field with JavaScript, not sure how you would be able to use the value if you could not read it. The console has no clue it is a password, it is just a string to it.

Comment: @KarlReid Yeah, thats what I was thinking too. It would be all too easy to write an extension that selects on fields with the password type and relays this data back to the author.

Comment: I think this is always bad practice to log sensitive data on console. But it depends on environment you are working on. CAUTION if you left as above.

Comment: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/security/faq.md#What-about-unmasking-of-passwords-with-the-developer-tools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of all textual input controls is the text that was typed in it, irrelevant if it is a password input or not. The only difference that `type="password"` makes is that it obscures the text in the web view.

You can even call up the Dev Tools to inspect a password textbox, change `type="password"` to `type="text"` and BAM you suddenly see the plain text that you typed.